# How can I insert variables as values in a dict

Tags: python, json, string, dictionary

I'm trying to generate a json payload to POST to an API, but I'm having trouble to make it work.

This is what I have now;

```
def payload(user, macro_hostname, macro_servicedesc, macro_servicestate, macro_serviceoutput,nagios_url):
    payload = { 'username': '%s', 'text': '--- \n HOST: %s \n SERVICE: %s \n STATE: %s \n MESSAGE %s \n %s|see nagios for more information \n\n --- ' % user, macro_hostname, macro_servicedesc, macro_servicestate, macro_serviceoutput, nagios_url }
    return payload
```

Apart from the fact that it's ugly and not really pythonic, it also has the distinct feature of not working at all. I've tried different variations on this method, but I seem to be stuck on trying to make this work; unfortunately I really haven't found a way to get this to work at all.

I'm aware that str.format() is preferred over the %s method, but I'm pretty sure there's a completely different way of doing what I want that's infinitely better than what I'm trying to do now.

Comment: "it also has the distinct feature of not working at all." - Could you tell us what went wrong?

Comment: What basically went wrong is that I probably didn't know enough about string-formatting to actually debug my issue. Anil's answer worked like a charm for me; I should really look up a nicer way to do this eventually; but at least it's working for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you are making a mistake in the initialization of the string for your dictionnary --> error in string formating
Move your `user` variable next to your firs item in the dictionnary and add parenthesis in your last variable.

```
def payload(user, macro_hostname, macro_servicedesc, macro_servicestate, macro_serviceoutput,nagios_url):
    payload = { 'username': '%s' %user, 
            'text': '--- \n HOST: %s \n SERVICE: %s \n STATE: %s \n MESSAGE %s \n %s|see nagios for more information \n\n --- ' % (macro_hostname, macro_servicedesc, macro_servicestate, macro_serviceoutput, nagios_url) }
    return payload
```

Comment: The other guy who commented had a working solution; but yours works great as well and actually looks nicer. Thanks!

Comment: I actually liked his code better, I just wrote it this way to keep with what you wrote so you could compare with yours and fix. For the next time: write the error you're having.